# tracert fails on last hop for some computers

Tags: networking, webserver, traceroute

I have moved a website from another host to my own VPS server. I also moved it from https to regular http.

When my client tries to access the website, he gets timed out. From my computer it works fine, and I've tried from a few different locations without issue.

The weird thing is that when I do a tracert from his computer, it times out at the very last hop.

According to my research, his computer/router/ISP could be sending a package that is not accepted by my server. Any ideas as to what this could be?

Comment: (include) -w xxxx after tracert.... to extend default wait (millisec) for result rather than timeout

Comment: Thank you, this will give me some extra information, but I doubt it will get me to the solution, since it's timing out consistently for him.

Comment: Does ping domain name convert to IP# on both?  if not then DNS server is  different

Comment: Yes, DNS seems fine. Same problem when doing tracert for the IP. Also same problem for other sites on the same server.

Comment: then client IP is blocked VPS from responding to ping for some reason

Comment: So, maybe DDOS protection or something like that?

Comment: Try other ports like ftp or http  port forwarding required in your router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the server blocked some IPs, probably because they are trying to reach the site via https while the new server does not yet have a SSL certificate installed.

This did not apply to all clients. Some had no problems accessing the new server on normal http although they had been accessing the site on the old https server before. This is what made the problem a bit more difficult to track down.

Removing the blocked IPs from the firewall's DENY list did the trick. And now they seem to be connecting fine.